# How to build a set of predicates? Is it even possible without Paradoxes?

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers, second-order-logic

This is how I have constructed a set of predicates for an object $x$. However, I am not sure how correct this construction is, or if it is, at all possible, to construct a set of predicates.
So, in essence, I am trying to build a set $A$ whose members are all the predicates of an object $x$.

$$A=\{\varphi|\varphi:x\to\text{{true}}\}$$

Now, I want to to go a step further and say:

$$B=\{\rho|\rho:A\to\text{{true}}\}$$

Here, I am trying to define the Set $B$ whose elements are all the predicates of the set $A$.

How good are the formalisms, anything missing?

I think people are still having a hard time understanding what I am trying to ask. I am saying is it possible to create a set $A$ such that whose elements are all the predicates of a particular object $x$. $P_{1}...P_{n}\in A$, where $P_{1}...P_{n}:x\to\text{{True}}$

Comment: [Already asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963741/building-a-set-of-predicates) some hours ago.

Comment: @mrtaurho I deleted that question, this is the refined version. I put some details in this version because people were not understanding the original question.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA My question was not answered. If I recall correctly you essentially gave me the syntax of set theory. However, I have a very particular question. This is as narrowed down as i could make it.

Comment: "Your [two] questions were not answered." Exactly: it is still there: what's the benefit of reiterating it ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I deleted the last one. I made some changes in this version because no one understood what I was trying to say. I tried making it clearer. However, If I still don't get an answer for it, I will not ask it again. Sorry.

Comment: This is not about set theory. Please do not add the tag back. I doubt the elementary-set-theory tag is appropriate either, but I'll leave it up to you whether to include it.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I will not put those tags back on. However, If you don't believe my question is relevant to set theory, then you could have told me why. At least that way I could find my answer too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this if you use [type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory). It comes in many versions, and isn't as popular as set theory. If $x$ is a first-order object, the predicates it satisfies are second-order, and the collection of them you call $A$ is third-order. By the same logic, $B$ is a fifth-order object; so you'll need a type theory with at least five types (not all have infinitely many).

There are several alternative approaches. You can take a theory of order $<5$, then add enough metalanguage layers to get the complexity you need. Or you could slightly modify your ambitions, and get by in a first-order set theory. How? We could fix a set $x$ and define $A$ as the set of [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe)-minimal sets of which $x$ is an element, and $B$ as the set of rank-minimal sets of which $A$ is an element. (You can then prove $\{ x\}\in A,\,\{ A\}\in B$.) That might not be exactly what you intended, but at least it's somewhat consistent with what most foundational mathematics does. For example, a common definition of the cardinal of a set $x$ is the set of *rank-minimal* sets that can form a bijection with $x$. The rank constraint is used to ensure the result is a set.

If you'd prefer a type=theoretic approach, be warned it has [its own meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism#Higher-ranked_polymorphism) for "rank".